# How can I read multiple COM ports?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have two Arduino Pro mini projects. These two Arduino's are sending data to me simultaneously. I don't send to data. I want to read these ports on Python(PC or Raspberry Pi). My baundrate is 9600. What kind of path should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) to monitor the different Com ports.
Run two instances of Putty at the same time and monitor the com ports.

Comment: Yes it really worked. Thank you so much :) If you know a method via Python or Matlab, can you share it with me?

Comment: @DiaHozier Im glad I could help if you could kindly mark the Answer as working to help others who may come across the same issue :)